# Wordpress, javascript and character enconding

Tags: javascript, wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a wordpress forum, and in a post I have included some javascript code through an external js file.

In this file I have a function that modify the content of a textbox of the wordpress post.

It works fine, but the problem is that when i have to write something in that textbox that contains a letter with an accent I can't get it right.

I should get an 'à" but I get a '�'.

I've added the charset="UTF-8" to this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="/myscript.js"></script>
```

but it doesn't work.

I've tried writing in the js '\u00E0' or '& agrave;' but I get the same result.

Someone knows what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance,

Claudio

Comment: Did you try to add <meta charset="utf-8">  tot the HTML file where you are including your Javascript file?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes, it's already included in every wordpress page, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @user3078620 Did you find a solution for this?